# SQL Outer Join to show rows with no data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need some help to get out some data and im stuck in the join swamp. I run on a MS SQL Server.

I have a list of clients in one table (clientgroup)

```
clientgroup
Groupid | clientid
1       | 11
1       | 12
1       | 13
1       | 14
1       | 15
```

And I have another table where I have if the clientid  has some clientactivity

```
clientcontactlog
Logid | clientid
1     | 11
2     | 14
3     | 15
4     | 11
5     | 11
6     | 11
```

Then I have another table with info about the clientactivity

```
contactlog
Logid | logtype | logdate      | logtext
1     | 1       | ’2016-05-16’ | ’Toys’
2     | 1       | ’2016-05-16’ | ’Toys’
3     | 1       | ’2016-05-16’ | ’Toys’
4     | 2       | ’2016-05-17’ | ’Lunch’
5     | 2       | ’2016-05-18’ | ’Dinner on Mars’
6     | 1       ! ’2016-05-19’ | ’Dinner on Mars’
```

I now want to make a mothly statistic (sum on logtypes in contactlog) about this and include all clients I have in my client list with id 1. So the output also shows the clients that have no record clientcontactlog. This is what I need help with.. I get all the data where we have input but I also need to show 0 on the clients that has no record.

Output should be

```
Clientname | sum(logtype1)
Client11   | 2
Client12   | 0
Client13   | 0
Client14   | 1
Client15   | 1
```

Thanks for input and help

Comment: Do you mean you want to include all clients with *`groupid`* 1?  And where does `clientname` come from?  None of the tables you've described have such a column.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like a typical left join to me.

Comment: Where's your query?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  In order to get the best answers, please post what you've already tried, and details about how you're stuck.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on asking good questions.

Comment: Where you have `SUM(logtype1)`, do you mean `MAX(logtype1)`? Your data would mean that the sum of logtype1 (which I assume is the same as  logtype in your clientactivity table) for Client11 would be 6, not 2. Can you clarify this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that you mean COUNT(LogType), not SUM(LogType), since Summing a date makes no sense whatsoever. In any case, this can do what you are asking for.

```
SELECT ClientName, IsNull(ct, 0) as LogCount
FROM clientgroup cg
INNER JOIN Clients c
    ON cg.clientid = c.clientid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT LogID, 
        Count(*) as ct
    FROM ClientContactLog
    GROUP BY ClientID
    ) as cl
```

Notes:

- I assumed a Clients table containing the client name.
- I am not looking at the contactlog table because it is not needed to provide what you are requesting.

Comment: I think the weird table formatting misled you, `LogType` is not a date

Comment: why isNull? ct will always be 0 or row count won't it? (sum would be a different story)

Comment: Count will - however, there won't necessarily be a COUNT for each ClientID, unless there is a row for that ClientID in the ClientContactLog table. In that case, a LEFT JOIN will return NULL in the syntax above. (I'm not sure about the other one - I'm not seeing a GROUP BY for that, so I think it has its own problems, but I haven't tested that structure.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a `client` table where the `clientname` column is, you can do that this way:

```
select  t2.clientname, coalesce(count(distinct t4.logtype), 0)
from    clientgroup t1
join    client t2
on      t1.clientid = t2.id
left join
        clientcontactlog t3
on      t1.clientid = t3.clientid
left join
        contactlog t4
on      t3.Logid = t4.Logid
where   t1.Groupid = 1
```

Comment: coalesce is unneeded isn't it? count will always return 0 or row count.